# Не могу выравнить изображения по низу

Tags: html, css

Получается, что картинки разного размера. Мне необходимо выравнить их по низу. а не по верху как сейчас. Свойство vertical-align не работает.

```css
.profit {
  padding-top: 50px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}

.profit_desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="profit">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://c.radikal.ru/c13/1712/c7/d92b5d4f5068.png" alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Использование канала продаж<br> в интернете

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b41/1712/57/ba009ae8cda9.png" alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Привлечение новых клиентов
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://c.radikal.ru/c41/1712/15/079369e4faa7.png
" alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Расширение возможностей бизнеса
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Юрий, как может

> margin: 0 в .profit? (это цитата из твоего коммента)

выровнять `img`? Обрати внимание на свой `HTML` и `CSS`, у тебя пример очень кривой.

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
```

Правила выше надо прописывать `родительскому` элементу, тебе надо было выровнять `img` по низу, а для `img` родителем является `<div class="card">`, а у него ни каких стилей нет. Выровнять элемент по центру можно по разному, в данном случае у `<div class="profit">` вообще не прописан `margin:0`, тебе надо было прижать `img` прижать к нижу, в данном случае это сделало правило `justify-content: flex-end;` у родительского элемента, но если бы у тебя в данном примере 
у `<div class="profit_desc">` не было бы фиксированной  высоты `height: 80px;`, то данный вариант решения не прокатил бы.

> P.S. Не сочти за высокомерие, но я бы тебе посоветовал, если ты хочешь и тебе надо уметь правильно верстать, `УЧИ CSS`. Вариантов добиться того или иного результата куча, все зависит от конкретного случая, вкуса и требований....

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

heml,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.profit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1170px;
  background: orange;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.profit_desc {
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  height: 80px;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="profit">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://c.radikal.ru/c13/1712/c7/d92b5d4f5068.png" alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Использование канала продаж в интернете

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b41/1712/57/ba009ae8cda9.png" alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Привлечение новых клиентов
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://c.radikal.ru/c41/1712/15/079369e4faa7.png
    " alt="">
    <div class="profit_desc">
      <p>
        Расширение возможностей бизнеса
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А получается для выравнивания по центру нужно использовать margin: 0 в .profit?

Comment: Юрий Brexston, почитай, я ответ изменил, там есть кое какие комментарии...

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего разобраться,добавив контейнерам `outline: 1px solid #цвет`

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: @Air В смысле не является? Я написал селектор выше,чтобы выровнять.

Comment: Александр, твое право, доказать мне обратное...

Comment: Судя по css,а именно по свойствам селектора profit_desc,я думаю человек бы сам увидел ошибку просто добавив контейнерам outline.И я также указал селектор чтобы выровнять.Пусть автор сам решает,полезно это ему или нет.